# Why do we use sum of radial forces in pendulums?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

**The problem is:** A small rock with mass m is fastened to a massless string with length L
to form a pendulum. The pendulum is swinging so as to make a maximum angle of theta with the vertical. Air resistance is negligible. What is the tension in the string when it makes an angle of theta with the vertical?

**My question is:** I understand that we use the fact that the sum of radial forces is $$\sum F_{rad} = T - mg\sin(\theta) = (m v^2)/r$$
where $(m v^2)/r = 0$ so $T = mg\sin(\theta)$, but why can't we use the fact that the sum of vertical forces, $$\Sigma F_y = Tcos(\theta) - mg = 0$$
to get $$T = mg/\cos(\theta)...?$$

**All we've learned in class so far is basic kinematics and dynamics, no simple harmonic motion yet

Comment: Because as others has noted, pendulum has vertical and horizontal acceleration components most of the time. So true equation would be $$T \cos \theta - mg = ma_v$$, where $a_v$ is vertical pendulum acceleration component. Thus, the rest of your conclusion part after sentence "_to get_", does not follow. Only in the bottom point pendulum has maximum speed and zero acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

The rock is accelerating vertically at (almost) all times during its motion.  So we cannot expect the vertical components of the forces to add to zero.